# When I click on the button, if the value of the button is 0, then the text will not show in that space. I mean, how can it be done without showing 10?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

When I click on the button, if the value of the button is 0, then the text will not show in that space. I mean, how can it be done without showing -10?

```
console.log(variable)
```

The this is the error I'm getting ..

```
const Mobile = () => {

   const [charge, setCharge] = useState(20)

   const setMobileCharge = () => setCharge(charge - 10)

   if (setMobileCharge === 0) {
      return 0;
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <h3>Charge : {charge}</h3>
         <button onClick={setMobileCharge}>Battery down</button>
      </div>
   );
};
```

export default Mobile;

Comment: Math.max(charge, 0)

Comment: My code was wrong .. const [charge, setCharge] = useState(20)

   const setMobileCharge = () => {
      if (charge === 0) {
         setCharge(0)
      }
      else {
         setCharge(charge - 10)
      }

   }
Right code this

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the react "ticks" your render is not fully synced with the state ... so to prevent that you can set the new state like that

```
setCharge(oldCharge => oldCharge -10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition like below,

```
const Mobile = () => {

    const [charge, setCharge] = useState(20)
 
    const setMobileCharge = () => {
      if(charge > 0) setCharge(charge - 10)}   //here
 
    if (setMobileCharge === 0) {
       return 0;
    }
 
    return (
       <div>
          <h3>Charge : {charge === 0 ? "" : charge}</h3>   //here
          <button onClick={setMobileCharge}>Battery down</button>
       </div>
    );
 };
```

Comment: don't working bro . count -10 .. I'm not interest count minus .. when count value is 0 then stop 0 . like this .. How to do ?

Comment: check now, it will not update value after charge is 0 and will display nothing when charge is 0

Comment: and if you want 0 to show then remove condition at <h3>

Comment: my code is was wrong ....const [charge, setCharge] = useState(20)

   const setMobileCharge = () => {
      if (charge === 0) {
         setCharge(0)
      }
      else {
         setCharge(charge - 10)
      }

   }
right code this

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't quite understand your question.
But if you want when 0 not to decrease, you can :

```
const setMobileCharge = () => {
  if (charge > 0) {
   setCharge(charge - 10)
  }
}
```

If you want when 0 Mobile component disappear you can:

```
if (charge === 0) {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want the when -(minus) not to show when my charge amount is 0. Means will be closed at 0. Don't fall below that. how to do ?